# How to implement an alarm on Android that turns off via an action on another screen?

Tags: android, time, alarm, timepicker

I'm trying to create an Android alarm that will turn off when an action is completed on another screen (i.e. a user types an answer into a math problem).

How do I:

1. allow user to set their daily alarm on screen with timepicker
2. implement that alarm
3. allow user to turn off the alarm by doing the math problem (or any
   other action) on another screen

I tried following this example with the suggested solution: [Unable to set alarm time in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236102/unable-to-set-alarm-time-in-android)

but it doesn't play a ringtone. I added this right under the line

```
Toast.makeText(BrainBuzzActivity.this, "Alarm has been set.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
if(alert == null){
     // alert is null, using backup
     alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
     if(alert == null){
        // alert backup is null, using 2nd backup
        alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);               
     }
}
```

ORIGINAL Main Page (creation of intent)

```
    public class BrainBuzzActivity extends Activity 
    {
        private Button alarm = null;
        private AlarmManager alarmManager = null;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        static final int DIALOG_TIME = 0;


alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alarm);
    alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_TIME);
        }
    });
}

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch(id){
    case DIALOG_TIME:
        dialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                // c.clear();
                //c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
                //c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
                //c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                //c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                Intent intent = new Intent(BrainBuzzActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(BrainBuzzActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);
                Toast.makeText(BrainBuzzActivity.this, "Alarm has been set.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(BrainBuzzActivity.this, CloudCapture.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        },cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false);
        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an alarm, you use the `AlarmManager` method

[`setInexactRepeating(int type, long triggerAtTime, long interval, PendingIntent operation)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

so you can calculate the difference between now and when you want it to go off, and then specify the length until each subsequent alarm.

To cancel an alarm you have to create a PendingIntent of the same *kind*, which is defined in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) as

> same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags

and then use

[`cancel(PendingIntent operation)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: Hi, so in my main activity, the PendingIntent is defined as

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainPage.this, 0, intent, 0);

How do I cancel in the other class? I tried

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainPage.this, 0, intent, 0);
cancel (pi);

Sorry for being n00by...

Comment: How are you creating the `intent`? Edit your original question with that code